# Web service/api for iPhones app

Tags: iphone

I am hiring a freelancer to develop a social networking app for iPhones with event creation, messaging, etc.  He asked me if I was going to provide web services/api.  I am completely new to app and web development so I am not sure how to answer.  If I provide those things, what do I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get it very clear in your head what you want to build before you hire a freelancer. If you don't you'll be in a costly world of pain very quickly.

So, sit down and think, if you have a friend developer maybe you can have a chat with him and decide the architecture of the product.

What that guy asked you is if you need an API to provide data which is a fair question. Think of a source of your data where other applications can connect and interact with it.

The answer is yes you will need an api because all the mobile clients need to connect to something and that something will be an Api. The Api will be the bridge between your data and your clients. The data will reside into a database so that's another thing to consider.

As I said, think very well what you want because the quality of what any freelancer will build, depends on the quality of information you provide. If it's not clear in your head then it won't be pretty.